# Is there any way to delete label or button from tkinter window and then add it back?

Tags: python, tkinter

Something like this:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

but = Button(root, text = "button")
but.pack()
#When I try:
but.destroy()
but.pack()
```

I get an error:

> TclError: bad window path name ".37111768"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `pack_forget` method will hide the widget and you can pack or grid it again later.
http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm

Comment: If you are hiding and restoring widgets, `grid` is the better choice since it can remember where the widget originally was.

Answer (score 10):

I have managed to get it working :) here is my work:

```
from Tkinter import *
def changebutton():
    but.destroy()
    secondbut=Button(root,text="changed")
    secondbut.pack()
if __name__=='__main__':
    root=Tk()
    global but
    but= Button(root,text="button",command=changebutton)
    but.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```