# Tkinter Error: Bad window path name

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to include a stats menu for my game (seen here):

```
def statsexpand():
    toplevel = Toplevel()
    toplevel.destroy()
    if "normal" != toplevel.state():
        toplevel = Toplevel()
        totalclicksvar = StringVar()
        totalclicksvar.set("Total Clicks: " + str(totalclicks))
        totalclickslabel = Label(toplevel, textvariable=totalclicksvar)
        totalclickslabel.pack()
```

...which unfortunately doesn't work, and comes up with this issue.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/hyli/Desktop/New folder (2)/Ways to NOT earn money V0.4.0.py", line 14, in statsexpand
    if "normal" != toplevel.state():
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1772, in wm_state
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'state', self._w, newstate)
  TclError: bad window path name ".28950040"
```

I have checked other questions on this site for answers, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879255/is-there-any-way-to-delete-label-or-button-from-tkinter-window-and-then-add-it-b) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27223165/pythonbad-window-path-name-when-using-deiconify), yet they don't really apply to this question in hand.

For the rest of the code (if needed), see https://github.com/DerpfacePython/Ways-to-NOT-make-money/blob/master/game.py.

Please help!

Comment: Briefly: you destroyed the window and then tried to work with it.

Comment: But... duplicate of what?

Comment: The link to the duplicate appears at the top, between the question's title and its body. Anyway, all you'll find there is "you can't do things with it after destroying it."